# How to disable dates in React nice dates?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using this Calendar library from https://reactnicedates.hernansartorio.com/. I am using `<DatePickerCalendar />` component from the library.

I have an array with three dates.

```
[date1, date2, date3]
```

How can i disable these three dates in the calendar. In the context of that user cannot pick these dates. In the API docs there is a reference to  modifier object which takes a callback to modify the days in the calendar but i am struggling to implement this. Any suggestion? Thank you

https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-dust-vkuhz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: A Codesandbox with what you've tried so far could come in handy. Or at least some code...

Comment: Perhaps, if you replace the example comparison (getDay(date) === 6) with a check on these 3 days would work for you? (The Array includes method might come in handy here)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-dust-vkuhz?file=/src/App.js this is all i got so far, three dates that i want to disable, all three are in the future

Comment: Where are your 3 dates in the code?

Comment: const datesArray = [
  new Date(2021, 8, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  new Date(2021, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  new Date(2021, 9, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0)
];   they should be on line 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `disabled` modifier and run an Array loop check on the values as follows:

```js
...
import { isEqual } from "date-fns"; // Importing isEqual to compare dates

const datesArray = [
  new Date(2021, 8, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  new Date(2021, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  new Date(2021, 9, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0)
];

const modifiers = {
  disabled: (date) => {

    // The `some` method will check whether one of the values
    // of the Array passes the test (true):
    const isDisabled = datesArray.some((dateToDisable) =>
      isEqual(dateToDisable, date)
    );

    return isDisabled;

  },
...
```

The rest of the code, remains as is.

**Make sure** to include valid dates in the `datesArray`.

Comment: the three dates are still selectable, i don't think it worked. You can check codesandbox.

Comment: Oct 1 and Oct 3 are disabled. The 1st date is invalid.